# How to select install directoy based on operating system in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I have created EXE using nsis script.currently I have set the install directory this path

**InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\myapp**.

I have run exe file in windows xp,windows 7 32 bit and win7 64 bit.
Installation directory may change xp and window 7.

How to find if the os is window 7 or window xp?

How to select installation directory based on os?

Answer (score 3):

Selecting the destination based on the OS is not usually something you should do but if you really want to you can use `WinVer.nsh`:

```
!include WinVer.nsh

Function .onInit
${If} ${AtLeastWinVista}
  StrCpy $InstDir "c:\VistaAndLater"
${Else}
  StrCpy $InstDir "c:\Win95To2003"
${EndIf} 
FunctionEnd
```

If you want to change it based on x86 vs AMD64, use `x64.nsh`

Comment: @Anders.Thanks.If i run win7 64 bit it take pgm files(86) by default.if i run win 7 32 bit it take pgm files by default.How to manage this?

Comment: Just using $ProgramFiles should do that. There is also $ProgramFiles32 and $ProgramFiles64...

Comment: $ProgramFiles should manage both the 32 and 64 versions? How can it find which version(32 or 64) of os running?

Comment: @ILLA if you just go for $ProgramFiles nsis automatically chooses Program Files on 32 bit machines and Program Files (86)  on 64 bit machines (assuming u r using 32 bit nsis installer - most commonly seen).